# why is the item not getting a sum in the count?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run this code to check if there's already a product in the cart and if that product already exists, add one to the count of it. Else, add that item to the item array which is where I store all the items that are being added. But whenever an item already exists, the count doesn't get an add up but instead it just keeps returning 0. Why can that be?

When I console log it to debug it, it just prints `count: NaN`

This is my JS code:

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import data from './data.js'
import useCountsContext from './context/useCountsContext.js'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');

function Shop({ data }) {
  const {count, setCount} = useContext(useCountsContext)
  const {item, setItem} = useContext(useCountsContext)

  const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.forEach((product) => {

       const exists = item.findIndex((i) => i.img  === product.img) > -1;

       if (exists) {
            item.count += 1
         console.log(item)
       }  else if (product.id === productsId) {
          setItem(item.concat(product))
        }
      })
  }

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
          {data.map(({id, img, button}) => (
            <>
              <img className="img___shop" key={id} src={img}></img>
              <div key={id}>
                <button onClick={() => addCart(id)}>{button}</button>
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

This is my data file:

```
   import diCaprio from './img/diCaprio.jpg'
    import steveJobs from './img/steveJobs.jpg'
    import lips from './img/lips.jpg'
    import buda from './img/buda.jpg'
    import spaceDog from './img/spaceDog.jpg'
    import astroNube from './img/astroNube.jpg'
    import banksy from './img/Banksy.jpg'
    import banksyDJ from './img/banksyDJ.jpg'
    var uniqid = require('uniqid');
    
    
    const data = [{
      id: uniqid(),
      title: "Steve Jobs",
      img: steveJobs,
      homeImg: steveJobs,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: uniqid(),
      img: diCaprio,
      homeImg: diCaprio,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: uniqid(),
      img: lips,
      homeImg: lips,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: uniqid(),
      img: buda,
      homeImg: buda,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: uniqid(),
      img: spaceDog,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: uniqid(),
      img:astroNube,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: uniqid(),
      img: banksy,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: uniqid(),
      img:banksyDJ,
      button: "add to cart",
      count: 0
    }
    ]
    
    export default data;
```

Comment: Is item an array or an object? You call both findIndex and .count on it.

Comment: it is an array with object items. It is the data file that i've put below

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, item.count is undefined. item is an array of objects. Your shorthand `item.count += 1` does, `item.count = item.count +1;`
undefined + 1 is NaN so item.count is NaN.

Again you are not updating state in first if condition with setItem, you are **mutating** the state which is not recommended and react won't even detect a change so no re-render.

You can create a copy of the array , so you have a new reference. Then update your specific object property.

```
let findInd = item.findIndex((i) => i.img  === product.img);
 const exists = (findInd > -1);

if (exists) {
          let newArry = [...item];
         let newObj = { ...newArry[findInd]};
newObj.count++;
         console.log(newArry)
  setItem(newArry);
       }
```

Side note: I hope any of your for loop condition is being called only once. I don't think putting setState inside a loop is a safe way to update state.

Comment: the count only gets added once... aswell, then when it is clicked another time it doesn't get added

Answer (score 0):

The useState setter function like setCount are **asynchronous** which means that the code is not executed sequentially and so your logic is wrong in trying to get the new count value right after setting it.

What you can do is use (count + 1) instead of count during the function and at the end call the setCount(count + 1)

Comment: yes but those are different. One is to output the count of the number of items in the cart before the cart is clicked. The other count is to output the quantity of items in the cart for each particular product.